# string.StartsWith element from the list

Tags: c#, string, startswith

Here is my code:

```
private bool isSpecialZone(string zoneNumber, string clientName)
{
    var notSpecialZones = new List<string> { "200", "201", "202" };
    return clientName.Contains("XXX") && !zoneNumber.StartsWith("200") && !zoneNumber.StartsWith("201") && !zoneNumber.StartsWith("202");
}
```

I would like to make it cleaner and instead of repeating the "StartsWith" everywhere have one statement. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This is now answered better by Bart. This naming is pretty confusing to be honest, "doesn't contain not special zone" - try to find something without "not" if possible.

Comment: @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev Thank You, I've tried Your answer as well as it was before nad it worked as well. I'm going to think about the naming then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This next linq statement does exactly what you want. 
As soon as it sees the zoneNumber starts with a 'notSpecialZone' it stops and returns.
By supplying the '!' we reverse the result so it matches the method.

```
private bool isSpecialZone(string zoneNumber, string clientName)
{
    var notSpecialZones = new List<string> { "200", "201", "202" };
    return clientName.Contains("XXX") && !notSpecialZones.Any(zone => zoneNumber.StartsWith(zone)); 
}
```

Comment: You have lost the client name :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, Thank you, I adjusted the method to include the clientName

Comment: @Bart Thank You. It worked. I would have remembered about client name anyway, but thanks. ;)